# Javascript 2 times "Hello World" in one function. Why isn't this working?

Tags: javascript

Could someone explain why this aint working:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function helloWorld() {
$("#info").html("Hello World 1");
$("#info2").html("Hello World 2");
}
 </script>
</head>
<input type="submit"  onClick="helloWorld()"/>
<div id="info" />
<div id="info2" />
```

(it's not showing "Hello World 2" also)

Comment: `</div>` close with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly close your divs. Divs cannot be self-closed within the DOM itself.

```js
function helloWorld() {
  $("#info").html("Hello World 1");
  $("#info2").html("Hello World 2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="submit"  onClick="helloWorld()"/>

<div id="info"></div>
<div id="info2"></div>
```

Here's a reference to all HTML elements that can be self-closed:

http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html#void-element

Comment: ` Divs cannot be self-closed ` so does input element ??

Comment: Inputs **can** be self-closed.